# uWSGI uses Python 2.7 instead of 3.5 which causes consequential errors

Tags: python, django, raspberry-pi, python-3.5, uwsgi

I'm trying to create a Django app with WebSockets on a Raspberry Pi 2 using `django-websocket-redis` pip package. `/manage.py runserver` doesn't seem to work (got 404 calling `/ws/` although it's set by `WEBSOCKET_URL = '/ws/'` in `settings.py`), I wanna try a standalone uWSGI  server like [described here in the official docs](http://django-websocket-redis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running.html).

When I run `uwsgi`, I got strange errors. I think this is caused by a wrong python version. The output of `uwsgi` show me that Python 2.7 is used:

```
Python version: 2.7.13 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:48:08)  [GCC 6.3.0 20170124]
```

But I need Python 3 (exactly 3.5) for my project. I changed the default python environment, so that the `python` comamnd points to python 3.5 instead of 2.7. Additionally, I passed the version using `--plugin` switch like this:

```
uwsgi --http :9090 --plugin=python35 --wsgi-file wsgi.py
```

I also used `pip3`for all pip packages to make sure that no 2.x packages were used. This seems having no effect, cause my script breaks and `uwsgi` show me that Python 2.7 is used...

Comment: You shouldn't change the default Python, that will likely break your system. You should instead install uwsgi for the version of Python you want to use.

Comment: I did this using `pip3` which should install packages for Python3. But that hasn't worked, since 2.7.13 is still used instead of 3.5... So I thought uwsig may used `python` as default, which doesn't work, too.

Comment: How did you build the python35 plugin?

Comment: Try setting pyhome to point your virtualenv:
[uWSGI pyhome](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html#pyhome)

Comment: I am facing the same issue, i want my project to run on python 3.5, could you please help me with the steps. This is the exact issue i am facing. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

install this:

```
sudo apt-get install uwsgi-plugin-python3
```